# getting infinite output impedance in Ltspice but not by manual analysis

Tags: cmos, ltspice

I am a beginner to LTSpice, I make this simple netlist:

```
*#destroy all
*#run
*#print all
.TF I(vmeas) vin
vin vin 0 DC 1
R1 vin vout 1k
R2 vout vmeas 2k
vmeas vmeas 0 DC 0
.end
```

I am using a test voltage source( 0 volts source) to calculate current through R2. When I run this simulation I get output Impedance as infinite. I dont get this, If its calculating the ipedance across vmeas then it should be zero since then it will be 0|| 3k and if its calculating output impadnce across vout then it should be 3k because while calculating impedance **we zero out the independent sources** so it means vmeas will become 0 volts , a plain wire.[image]

Comment: I never used `.TF`, so I can't help much, expecially since I tried with both IV and XVII versions and they yied the same results. I also tried a search on the LTspice Yahoo Groups for relevant posts, but couldn't find, even though I am certain there may have been some (rare) posts about this. Maybe it would help to also ask this question in the group? If you do, don't use attachements, they don't work. Instead, upload the picture in the group's image section. That simple netlist can be simply added inside the body of the message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.TF just doesn't seem to work in the expected way for the output impedance calculation when current is measured.

If you take that same circuit and change the .TF line to .TF V(vout) vin, it calculates the output impedance correctly.

The book [CMOS Circuit Design, Layout, and Simulation](http://cmosedu.com/videos/ltspice/CMOSedu_SPICE_Ch_1.pdf), from whence your example originated, it appears, has a cryptic 'explanation' that makes little sense to me:

[image]

For example, if you put resistors across the voltage sources, the output impedance is still open.

This problem has come up before on [this stackexchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/206964/tf-spice-simulation-output-impedance-with-current-as-output/207896) and on [Dave's eevblog](http://www.eevblog.com/forum/beginners/tf-spice-simulation-output-impedance-with-current-as-output/), where it received some attention but no definitive result. Whatever it is, it is baked into Berkeley SPICE and not an artifact of LTspice.

Comment: The picture made things click for me. It makes sense if you think about it: the measuring source, `V2`, is removed because it is meant to measure the *current*, that is, it should have been replaced by a *current source*, thus an infinite impedance. Adding parallel resistors across the measuring voltage source (or specifying `Rser`) does nothing since the element from those two points needs to be replaced by a current source (thus eliminated). This part seems fuzzy, but it kind of makes sense, even if it makes me wonder what would happen for a parallel branch where only one current is needed.